# Get Notification when My device get auto locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications

Can i get notification in my running app when device get auto locked?

any help ?

Comment: any kind of notification from which i know that my device is locked..

Comment: Have you looked at the UIApplicationDelegate methods? Or done a search here on SO?  Or on Google?

Comment: when my application is running and my device getting locked , is there any notification there so i know that devices is getting locked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

It will be sent to your app if the user hits the lock button, goes to sleep mode automatically or swithes to another app on multitasking phones.

Here is a good [UIApplication delegate overview](http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v122.pdf), covers this subject and a handful more you might run into.

Comment: if my device getting locked automaticaly then this code works?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean by "goes to sleep mode automatically"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you always get this notification, just watch:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: ya it is working , but can i know that this method getting called because of locked ?

Comment: it is getting called when i open my application from background

Answer (score 1):

There is not explicit notification for that afaik. The `applicationWillResignActive` will be called, but it will also be called when the app goes into the background through other means (like hitting HOME button, or switching to another app).

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code to get the state in applicationWillResignActive

```
 int notify_token;
 notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", &notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token) {
 uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;
 notify_get_state(token, &state); 
 if(state == 0) {
 NSLog(@"unlock device");
 } else {
 NSLog(@"lock device");
 }
```

Comment: It is possible in jailbroken phone only.